# How to display json data using react jsx with sweet alert 2?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sweetalert2

I am developing a script in react and nodejs. The idea is about displaying the content from json to the react page using sweet alert 2.

The output does not shows results which is suppose to display the content from the json file.

Here are my codes

```
import React from 'react';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
import withReactContent from 'sweetalert2-react-content';
const MySwal = withReactContent(Swal);
const json = require('json-loader!./myfilepath.json');
class pageJSONOCR extends React.Component
{

getData = () =>

{

    console.log("Button Clicked");

    MySwal.fire({

        title: 'Success!',

        text: "Button is clicked",

        type: 'success',

        showCancelButton: false,

        confirmButtonText: 'View File'

      }).then((result) => {

        if (result.value) {

            MySwal.fire(

                'The Content Of Json File',

                `${json}` 

          )

        }

      })

}

render()

{

    console.log("Header - Rendered");

    return(

        <div className="container">

            <div className="py-5 text-center">

                <div className="jumbotron">

                    <div className="container">

                        <h1>Out Put</h1>

                        <hr/>

                        <p className="lead">Check The JSON File</p>

                        <button className="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" onClick={this.getData}>Submit</button>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    );

}
}
export default pageJSONOCR;
```

If there is any solutions do help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

use sweetalert2-react-content

```
import withReactContent from 'sweetalert2-react-content';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

const basic = withReactContent(Swal.mixin({
  title: 'Success',
  text: 'text here.',
  confirmButtonText: "Okay.",
  showCloseButton: true,
  showCancelButton: true,
  cancelButtonText: 'Cancel'
}));

...
<div>
  {
    basic.mixin({
        title: <i>title</i>
      }).fire()
  }
</div>
```